# What about creating a Badge s) for "active participation" in the upper 10%?

Tags: feature-request, badges

On the Profile page the user's on-going activity in a Quarter is enumerated by percentage (7%, 12%, 50%, etc.)

For consideration, what would be the consensus of users (and moderators) about a new Bronze Badge created to honor users who remained in the upper 10% for a Quarter...and a Silver Badge for those who remained in the upper 10% for two consecutive quarters (or more?).

Would this encourage more participation?

Comment: I think this is a good idea with very little drawbacks.  It would promote positive use of the site. We mods don't have much say over it, but a Community Manager might pop in. If you get some upvotes. We haven't had many feature requests on our meta lately, but I think there's another tag I can apply to get their attention.